# jQuery multiple divs show hide only one at a time

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show, overlapping

Hello and let me first explain that I have not used jQuery very much at all.  Simple show and hide and basic UI is the extent.  So with that said, I am trying to be able to show a div, that is actually a "page" that has been linked to a "link".

Markup:

```
<body>
<!--Footer and Navigation Div's-->
<div id="bg"><img src="images/bg.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>S.E. <span>yoga</span></p>
            <div id="nav">
                <ul><a href="#">Link 1</a></ul>
                <ul><a href="#">Link 2</a></ul>
                <ul><a href="#">Link 3</a></ul>
                <ul><a href="#">Link 4</a></ul>
            </div>
    </div>
<!--END Footer and Navigation Div's-->

<div class="parent">
<div class="a">
        <p>this is a</p>
    </div>   
   <div class="b">
        <p>this is b</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
        <p>this is c</p>
    </div>
    <div class="d">
        <p>this is d</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
 /*
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#nav').click(function(){
        $(".a").slideToggle();
  var divname= this.value;
          $("#"+divname).show("slow").siblings().hide("slow");

    });
});*/ 

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.a, .b, .c, .d').hide();
});;
```

So the first script (commented out) I was using I was going to use as a starting point.  The second script, where they are all hidden is where I was going to go from.  Hide them all, then show only one at a time.

The divs are overlapping.  Any help?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you want them to show automatically one after another or when an event (such as click) occurs?
I think your question is not very clear.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Yes, this will be non linear.  As such, if the user clicks on "Link 1", the div for link 1 will show.  Likewise, if the user clicks on Link 4 then what ever div is currently viable will hide, and the div for Link 4 will show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.parent  div').hide(); // hide div's on load using parent class as a starting point     
         $('#nav a').click(function() {  // on the anchor clicks that are inside div with id=nav
            var $div = $('.parent div').eq($(this).index('#nav a'));  // get the relevant div
            $div.show();  // show the relevant div
            $('.parent div').not($div).hide();  // hide all but the relevant div
        });​
    }):
```

EDIT:

`$('.parent div')`  // <-- this gets all divs under the element with class parent

[.eq(index)](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) // will get the element at the given index which is the following

`$(this)` // <-- Current clicked anchor tag

`.index('#nav a');`  // <--  get the [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) of the current anchor tags compared to other other anchor tags

weird thing is I usually use $(this).index() and it works but this time it didn't so I had to specify a selector inside the index.

also fix your html to look like this instead

```
 <div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/HpCWW/1/

Comment: Thanks so much but I am not getting it to work.  If it's not too much trouble, can you explain how 
    
$('.parent div').eq($(this).index('a')); works?

Comment: @user1572036 I updated the fiddle and answer.  I didn't give it a specific enough selector for index() which might have caused your issue.  See if the new code will help you

Comment: Ok.  So in am getting the understanding of this now a little bit.  I code in actionscript and there is a "trace" command similar to that of the alert.  What I would like to know is can I put in alert("you clicked" + $div("name")); or is that not possible?

Comment: You want to alert which div or anchor was clicked?  The click event handler is not attached to the div.  But yes that's possible.  Just explain exactly what you want to happen.

Comment: Basically, I am commenting the code line by line and seeing if I can understand the process.  I have gotten to the point now where you click a link and a div is supposed to show, but the show part is commented out.  I just want to be able to click the button and an alert pops up telling me what button to press.   SO sorry for drawing this out.  I guess I should ask this in a different question.  Thanks for all your help so far!!!!!

Comment: Sorry, anchor is what I meant

Comment: inside the click event you can just add `alert('you clicked ' + $(this).text());`  Remember `$(this)` refers to the element that triggered the event.. then you can access it's text with text()

Comment: Right now it just says you clicked [Object object]

Comment: You're welcome.. also just FYI the only valid children of `<ul>`s are `<li>`s which might cause you more issues.  And if this answered your question don't forget to click the green check mark.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only one div at a time, consider using jquery accordion. http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Comment: Actually that is not what I am going for.  Basically, I am trying to get the same effect as this: http://www.wix.com/html-templates/html/web/close-up?utm_campaign=flash&experiment_id=ma_templatemo_temp_H_closeup